# How to make 1/4 inch beveled edge on unfinished walnut countertop

Tags: wood, woodworking, kitchen-counters

I had 6ftx4ft black walnut counter top delivered unfinished *(for cost savings reason)*. Please help me find out the best tool to use to make a 1/4 inch beveled edge for this rectangular piece of walnut. The thickness of this wood in 1-3/4 inch. I need to finish all 4 sides with beveled edge (30 deg beveled angle).

Answer (score 3):

The obvious first choice would be a router, as it would do this with precision and ease, but can be expensive. If you were careful, marked, measured and were patient you could use a jack plane for this.

Comment: For this job a small router (a.k.a. "laminate trimmer") should be fine, they can be had for less than $100. A decent full-sized router would also work great, less than $200.

Comment: @HenryJackson That's a good point. It it wasn't such a large piece, I almost suggested careful sanding with an orbital and 60 grit sandpaper, but figured he wanted it a bit more precise. I know I've accidentally put about that much bevel on some soft wood before with a sander like that.

Comment: Walnut isn't a very soft wood, though. My grandfather's done a lot of work with it, and I a little, and it's a true test for any woodworking tool. I would not recommend anything less than a full-size router to cut a bevel around 20 feet of walnut.

Comment: @KeithS You can do it, you just need to make multiple light passes and respect the power you possess in your tool. Just takes patience and a willingness to go slow.

Answer (score 0):

yes light passes removing an 1/32-1/16 inch each time, use a new router bit, and watch for "tear-out" (start at a corner and work inward).